# dependencies issue when compile library

Tags: android

I can't compile the line with Android Studio

> compile 'com.vanniktech:emoji-one:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT'

And error:

> Error:(53, 13) Failed to resolve: com.vanniktech:emoji-one:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT
>   Show in File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

This is emoji lib from vanniktech github, just want to show the emoji in my app.

> https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji

My build.gradle (level for app)

[image]
[image]

Any ideas for my issue ?

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: `compile 'com.vanniktech:emoji-google:0.5.1' compile 'com.vanniktech:emoji-google:0.6.0-SNAPSHOT'`

Comment: I added 2 line but only 1 line `compile 'com.vanniktech:emoji-google:0.5.1'` is succesfully.